# When do rvalue objects get destroyed when accessing their members as part of a function call?

Tags: c++

I've just been thinking about the following bit of code:

```
    PerformConflict(m_dwSession, 
        CONFLICT_DETECTED, 
        item.GetConflictedFile().GetUnNormalizedPath().c_str(), 
        item.GetSuggestedFile().GetUnNormalizedPath().c_str());
```

- `GetConflictFile()` returns an object.
- `GetUnNormalizedPath()`
  returns a `std::wstring`
- `c_str()` just returns a `const wchar_t*` (in this case to the contents of an rvalue `std::wstring`)

My question is: Does anything in the spec guarantee that this code is safe?  I.e. are all the rvalue objects guaranteed not to have been destroyed by the time that c_str() is getting a pointer to their contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to call temporary object's methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701313/is-it-safe-to-call-temporary-objects-methods)

Comment: Yes, it will be safe as long as you don't store the pointers. The temporary objects will be destroyed at the end of the statement (at the `;`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those temporaries will be destroyed at the end of the full expression they appear in. In your case, that's the entire snippet you posted.

This will be absolutely fine, so long as you *only* use that `const wchar_t*` inside that function invocation. If you store it anywhere and try to access it after the call exits, you would be thrust down the deep dark hole of UB.

---

The relevant standards quote is (emphasis mine):

> `N3337 [class.temporary]/3:`
>   When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor (12.1,
>   12.8), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be
>   called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor (12.4). **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.** This is true
>   even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side ef f ects of destroying
>   a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

Comment: A slight clarification might be handy: It's the storing of the *pointers* that could lead to UB if dereferenced. Also worth pointing out is that the strings pointed to should be considered read-only.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg isn't the read-only nature covered by the presence of `const`?

Comment: That is what I thought, I just couldn't find it in the spec.

Comment: @Benj it's in `[class.temporary]/3`. I can add the quote to the answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: Ahh thanks very much!  Yes I think it would be helpful if you have it to hand.

Answer (score 1):

As [illustrated by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), rvalues are destroyed at the end of the expression in which they appear. However, if you bind them to *"a reference to const on the stack"*, their lifetime is extended to that of the reference.

So, basically, if your function has this kind of signature:

```
PerformConflict(...,
                ...,
                const std::string& str1, //< any rvalue passed here will have the same lifetime as str1
                const std::string& str2  //< any rvalue passed here will have the same lifetime as str2
);
```

You should be able to manipulate the strings **inside `PerformConflict()`** without problems.

PS: the problem can also be solved if you pass the arguments by value (i.e. `const std::string str1`)

Comment: Note that this isn't lifetime extension, the lifetime of the temporary in this case is that of the function anyway.

Comment: Interesting although in this instance I don't control the interface of PerformConflict so it has to accept `const whchar_t*` rather than std::string refs.

Comment: @865719 my point was that lifetime extension is unrelated to this. The standard actually talks about this as an exception to lifetime extension.

Comment: @TartanLlama you're right, thanks for the clarification.